# What is the analog pin for on a Phidget 3051 Dual relay board?

Tags: arduino, power, analog, relay

I recently purchased a [Phidget 3051_1 Dual Relay board](http://www.phidgets.com/products.php?product_id=3051_1) with the intention of using it to switch on and off flourescent lamp ballasts (20W tubes) over a fish tank by connecting the relays to 110VAC and using an arduino on the control inputs. What I'm not quite sure about is the purpose of the analog input pin on the power connector. I think I can safely ignore it.

Is there any benefit I would gain by using the analog pin on the 5V power harness?

Also, do I need to worry about [load noise](http://www.phidgets.com/docs/3051_User_Guide#Load_Noise) from the ballasts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it looks like there is a buffer on the relay board.

From some googling around - [On the phidgets forum](http://www.phidgets.com/phorum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=3745):

> It only needs 5v and GND from the analog. You can just wire up a standard sensor cable to any 5v power source, and plug it into the relay board.

[Also](https://www.phidgets.com/phorum/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=5044):

> The black connector is for connecting the relays to +5V and ground. It just simply provides an easy way to get power from the analog inputs.
>
> The terminal blocks are for controlling the relays and labelled 0 and 1.
>
> I agree that the Product Manual should be more clear.

It's worth noting that the documentation for that board is **terrible**. I can't find the schematic anywhere. I'm guessing as to how the board works, based on the fact that it seems to have two ICs on it, and the controller it's connected to doesn't seem to have the facilities to drive the relay coil.

Really, I would strongly suggest you e-mail the manufacturer, and ask for the schematic. If they refuse, return the board, and don't purchase from them again.

---

### Re: "Load Noise"

This is **incorrectly titled**. What they are really talking about are *inductive loads*.
If your fish-tank lights use electronic ballasts, you're fine. Also, your bulbs are small enough that even with magnetic ballasts, I think you can probably get away without any sort of inductive kickback suppression.

You can tell if you have an inductive or electronic ballast simply by weight. If the ballast feels like it's got a bunch of steel in it (the ballast inductor), it's magnetic. If not, it's electronic.

Comment: @Octopus - Derp, you are correct.

Comment: @Octopus - fixed

Comment: aha! excellent slueth work. i kind of suspected as much but wanted to be sure. they shouldn't have stated "Powered by any device with an Analog Input" on that first link I provided, since no analog input is necessary. ~sheesh~